# Is Ada not telling Leon the truth?

Tags: resident-evil

In the *Resident Evil 2* remake, Robert Kendo, Kendo's daughter Emma, Leon, and Ada have [the following conversation](https://residentevil.fandom.com/wiki/Leon_meets_Kendo):

> Robert: Yeah, Emmie. Daddy’s here. I’m here, OK? Those fuckin’ things outside… Look what they did to us. You’re a cop. You’re supposed to know something—how did this happen!? HUH!? She was our sweet little angel…
>
> Emma: Mommy…?
>
> Kendo: Mommy’s sleeping, honey, OK? …Emma.
>
> [He takes his daughter in his arms and goes into the back.]
>
> Kendo (to Leon and Ada): Just go… Just give us some privacy.
>
> [He slams the door.]
>
> Leon (to Ada): You know, it’s one thing to keep the truth from me! But why him?

Is Ada not telling Leon the truth? Why is she keeping the truth from him?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the game to properly answer this, but Ada is very secretive at first about her motives and mission. Normally, I'd say that it's about them not letting Kendo know that there is no cure and that Emmie will become a zombie, but given the next bit has him killing her to save her from the transformation, it seems he already knows. And, well, with this being set after the first game, with much of the city zombies, it's not exactly a secret.

Comment: But why he says it’s “ok” to keep the truth from him?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, I'm not terribly familiar with the games, so I might be missing something, but my impression from reading summaries, and watching the screen, is that Leon is more annoyed by Ada's general secretiveness rather than any particular secret. His line, "You know, it’s one thing to keep the truth from me! But why him?" is that he doesn't like that she's keeping secrets from him, but he feels it's even worse with this grieving father.

She *is* keeping secrets from him, namely that she's a mercenary who's been contracted to get a sample of the virus, but he doesn't know that yet.